# ¿Como integrar peticiones ajax si tengo MVC?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola como puedo implementar ajax en si Mi sistema web php implementa MVC con el siguiente formato `Controller/action`

Answer (score -1):

Aca le dejo una solucion que puede resolver su asunto.
     // Identifico el componente que va a disparar la accion
    $('a.prueba').click(function (event) {

```
    // Asigna el valor a ser pasado a tu controladora
    dataString = $(this).attr('nombre'); 
        // inicio la llamada ajax 
        $.ajax({
        // Defino la Accion (POST,GET,PUT,DELETE, PATCH)
        type:"POST",
        // Paso la informacion de la controladora usando la url base
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller_name/",
        // Defino la data que va a ser pasado en la llamada ajax
        data:'dataString='+dataString,
        // Si la llamada es correcta, entro en success sino en error;
        success:function (data) {
        alert('test');
        }

    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Espero esto le ayude

Comment: Consideremos que publicar código sin explicarlo es difícil de entender y aplicar, dado el enunciado del OP esto donde iría? Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM por su comentario